# Python equivalent to Matlab function 'ellipke'

Tags: python, matlab

Is there a command/commands in Python equivalent to Matlab's `ellipke(M)` function?

`K = ellipke(M)` returns the complete elliptic integral of the first kind for the each element in M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could vectorize `mpmath.ellipk(m, **kwargs)` to work with arrays :

```
ellipke = numpy.vectorize(mpmath.ellipk)
```

But If you don't want to deal with `sympy`, you can define your own method using [scipy.integrate.quad](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html)

Answer (score 2):

Sympy's [mpmath.ellipk(m, **kwargs)](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/mpmath/functions/elliptic.html#mpmath.ellipk) can evaluate the complete elliptic integral of the first kind for you.

Comment: Is that the same as `elliptic_k`?